# Is the pair $(\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}, \|.\|)$ complete?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let's consider the set of real square matrices $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2} = \{A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{1} & a_{2} \\ a_{3} & a_{4} \end{bmatrix} : a_{i} \in \mathbb{R}\}$ with the norm $\|A\| = \max \{|a_{1}|, |a_{2}|, |a_{3}|, |a_{4}|\}$. Define the function $\|.\|: \mathbb{R}^{2\times2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{0\}: \|A\| = \max \{|a_{1}|, |a_{2}|, |a_{3}|, |a_{4}|\}$. I know that this is a normed space. Is the pair $(\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}, \|.\|)$ complete? Is the subset $X_{0} = \{A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{1} & a_{2} \\ 0 & a_{4} \end{bmatrix} : a_{i} \in \mathbb{R}\}$ a subspace?

My attempt:
Let's consider the set of real square matrices $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ with this norm. The norm $\|.\|$ satisfies conditions like non-negativity, homogeneity, and triangle inequality. However, the normed space $(\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}, \|.\|)$ is not complete due to the nature of the norm. Because of this norm, not all Cauchy sequences can converge.

The subset $X_{0} = \{A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{1} & a_{2} \\ 0 & a_{4} \end{bmatrix} : a_{i} \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a subspace, as any sequence where all matrices have a $0$ in the second row, second column, will converge to a matrix belonging to $X_{0}$. This implies that $X_{0}$ is a closed subspace.

**Edit for completeness:**

Every norm on a finite-dimensional vector space is complete.

Consider the finite-dimensional vector space $X = \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ equipped with the Frobenius norm $\|A\|_F = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}|^2}$ for any $A = [a_{ij}] \in X$.

Now, let $(A_k)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$ with respect to the Frobenius norm. This means that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $m, n \geq N$, $\|A_m - A_n\|_F < \epsilon$.

Since $X$ is finite-dimensional, we can express each matrix $A_k$ in terms of a basis. Let $\{E_{11}, E_{12}, E_{21}, E_{22}\}$ be the standard basis for $X$, where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with a 1 in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column, and zeros elsewhere.

Now, express each $A_k$ in terms of this basis:
$\[ A_k = \sum_{i,j=1}^{2} a_{ij}^{(k)} E_{ij}. \]$

The Cauchy condition implies that each entry $a_{ij}^{(k)}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, and therefore converges to a limit, let's say $a_{ij}$.

Now, define the matrix $B$ with entries $b_{ij} = \lim_{k \to \infty} a_{ij}^{(k)}$. This matrix $B$ is the limit of the sequence $(A_k)$ in $X$ with respect to the Frobenius norm.

This establishes that every Cauchy sequence in $X$ with respect to the Frobenius norm converges to a limit in $X$, making $X$ complete.

Every norm on a finite-dimensional vector space is equivalent to the Euclidean norm.
Let's consider the Frobenius norm $\|A\|_F$ on $X = \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ and the Euclidean norm $\|A\|_2$ (induced by the standard inner product).

To show the equivalence, we need to find constants $c_1, c_2 > 0$ such that for all matrices $A$ in $X$:
$ c_1 \|A\|_2 \leq \|A\|_F \leq c_2 \|A\|_2. $

Consider a matrix $A$ with entries $a_{ij}$. The Frobenius norm is given by:
$ \|A\|_F = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}|^2}. $

The Euclidean norm is given by:
$ \|A\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} (a_{ij})^2}. $

Now, let's compare these norms:
$ \|A\|_F = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}|^2} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} (a_{ij})^2} = \|A\|_2.$

Thus, we have $c_1 = 1$ for the lower bound.

Now, let's consider the upper bound. Note that for any matrix $A$, each term $|a_{ij}|^2$ is less than or equal to $(a_{ij})^2$. Therefore:
$ \|A\|_F = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}|^2} \geq \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} (a_{ij})^2} = \|A\|_2. $

Thus, we have $c_2 = 1$ for the upper bound.

This completes the proof that the Frobenius norm is equivalent to the Euclidean norm on the finite-dimensional space $X = \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$.

I'd be grateful if anyone could check if it's correct and let me know if there are any mistakes!

Comment: "is not complete due to the nature of the norm" - what does it mean, what is "nature" of the norm? "not all Cauchy sequences can converge" - why do you think so? Do you have a specific example of Cauchy sequence that doesn't converge?

Comment: Any finite-dimensional normed space is complete.

Comment: Oh I just meant that The norm in question is defined as the maximum absolute value of the entries in a matrix: ∣∣A∣∣=max{∣a1∣,∣a2∣,∣a3∣,∣a4|} What I understand not all Cauchy sequences in this space converge to a limit within the space. Specifically, there can be Cauchy sequences that converge to a limit that is not a 2x2 matrix with real entries.

Comment: @gerw I added an edit, can you look over to make sure I left no mistakes

Comment: I'm not sure where the comment disappeared for the euclidean norm but I have tried to fix it according to your correction. If its incorrect can you maybe answer the question and show me what I have been doing wrong? Because I am really at a loss here

Comment: @Proloffc6 "What I understand not all Cauchy sequences in this space converge to a limit within the space" - do you have a specific example?

Comment: Also, claim in second part of your post ("every norm on a finite-dimensional vector space is complete") contradicts the first (that you vector space is complete).

Comment: If it is not too much of a bother can you show me how it should be corrected?

Comment: The norm you are considering is equivalent to the Euclidean and the Frobenius norm, as it is a finite-dimensional vector space. Then, as completeness is a property that equivalent norms share, your norm should also induce a complete normed space, as that happens for the Euclidean and the Frobenius norm. For some intuition, you can think of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ with the max-norm over coefficients as $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the $\infty$-norm.